# How to assign an entered value on a TextField to a String property?

Tags: c#, winforms, javafx, scenebuilder

I made a project in C# and I'm now trying to translate it to JavaFX, using IntelliJ IDEA and Gluon Scene Builder

I have some doubts:

1. How to assign an entered value on a `TextField` to a `String` property? I've done many Google searches and still can't figure this out.

   My code in C#:

   ```cs
   //Declaring and Initializing pFirstName Property
   public string pFirstName { get; set; } = "";

   ...

   //Assigning value entered in txtBox_PatientFirstNam to pFirstName
   Pat.pFirstName = txtBox_PatientFirstNam.Text;
   ```

   How would this look like in JavaFX?
2. How to rename controls in Gluon Scene Builder? Wasn't able to find this option yet, for example in WinForms I can rename a `TextBox` to `txtBox_PatientFirstNam`, but I don't know how to rename `TextField`s in Scene Builder

I'm stuck after spending a day learning how to design GUIs in Scene Builder, so thanks in advance to anyone willing to help me.

Comment: For 2), the `fx:id` attribute in the FXML file (which you can set for each control in Scene Builder) maps to the field name in the controller. As an aside, it's preferred that you don't ask multiple questions in a single post on this site (it makes it harder for other users to search them, for a start).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java to get the string value of a filed is:

```
string text = aTextField.getText()
```

To assign

```
aTextField.setText("string");
```

Comment: Great, thanks, but how can I individually identify my TextFields? ALL HBoxes are called just "HBox", same thing with VBoxes and TextFields... Every TextField is just "TextField" in maingui.fxml, and I see no graphical option in SceneBuilder to rename the controls

Comment: @etcCoder Set the `fx:id` of the control, then add the appropriate field into the controller so that it will be injected. Check out [Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).